# What is the real used space on data partition of my phone?

Tags: file-system, partitions, twrp, es-file-explorer

When selecting data partition on my phone (HTC One M8), TWRP says it's going to back up 5448 Mb. But 'df' command says there are 8319 Mb used from 10934 total. And ES Explorer displays the size of /data directory as 11.32 Gb.
How are these figures related? I'm at a loss trying to explain that.

Here is the screenshot of DiskInfo:

[image: Here is the screenshot of DiskInfo:]

Here is the screenshot of Diskusage:

[image: Diskusage]

Comment: Give us the screenshot of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo&hl=en)'s default page.

Comment: @Firelord, done.

Comment: Great. Would you tell us how much space is used by Internal SD card the moment? Perhaps tapping that **Data (userdata)** would provide insights. Otherwise, see if [Diskusage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en) tells you that. Do give us the screenshots of course. Out of 5.448GB at least 2GB is confirmed from the screenshot. We just now have to confirm how much /data is consumed by apps  and misc files.

Comment: @Firelord, done. System is another partition and doesn't count in 5448 Mb. Okay, I'm starting to see the answer to my question. It seems that ES File Explorer is wrong about the size of /data directory.